# Binary matrix combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

If I have an nxn matrix, and each value is either 0 or 1 but all 1s are adjacent when viewing the matrix as a square, how can I calculate the number of possible different matrices that could be generated if these conditions are true? I have tried to research for a solution unsuccessfully for this specific problem.

For example,
$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ would be valid however $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ would not.

Comment: Is the zero matrix allowed?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Yes, it is.

Comment: I doubt a sensible closed form exists...I suggest working it out for small $n$ and searching OEIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nonzero ones are here:
https://oeis.org/A059525

Add $1$ if you want all of them.

Comment: [+1] Congratulations. Please, say how you have found the right sequence ? Have you made a computer-aided inventory for $n=2, n=3, n=4$ ? My first thought was to find something connected to polyominoes... but it has remained at the state of a thought...

Comment: No, I just did some keyword searches at oeis.  Some combination of connected subgraph matrices binary

Comment: Thanks for your answer. OEIS is a fantastic tool !